# If a limit is $>0$ for any sequence approaching the limit values from a given direction, does the limit have to be $>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Suppose we are consider the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0,y\to 0} f(x)-g(y)
$$
along the direction $\theta$ (and assume that this limit exists).

If, for every (sub?)sequence $(x_1,y_1)\dots (x_n,y_n)$ along the direction $\theta$ it is true that
$$
f(x_k) - g(y_k)>0\quad \forall k=1,\dots,n
$$
then is it true that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)> \lim_{y\to 0 } g(y)
$$
along the direction $\theta$?

---

I think the answer should be "yes", because then for any $\epsilon$ I can get "close enough" to the limit such that $
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)> lim_{y\to 0 } g(y)
$

Aside: I specify the (sub?)sequence as $(x_i,y_i)$ -- i.e. as pairs --  because if we are approaching along a direction then the $y$ value is determined by the $x$-value I think (at least this is true for approaching along a line)

Comment: Do you assume your first limit exists? (i.e. $f-g$ is continuous in $0$?)

Comment: @LL3.14 OH, yes! thank you, I meant to specify that, and will now do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f-g$ is continuous in $0$, then we can denote by $c = \lim_{x,y\to 0} (f(x)-g(y))$, and by the sequential characterization of the limit, if $(x_k,y_k)\to 0$, then $f(x_k)-g(y_k)$ converges and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)-g(y_k) = c.
$$
Since $f(x_k)-g(x_k)≥ 0$ for every $k$, then
$$
0≤\lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_k)-g(y_k) = c = \lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x)-g(y).
$$
Of course, you will not have a strong inequality (imagine for example $f(x)-g(y) = |x|^2+|y|^2$)

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify "you will not have a strong inequality"? You mean that $\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x)-g(y)$ will be $=0$, not ever $>0$? That seems weird to me? (constant functions $f(x)=5 $, $g(x)=4$ seems like a counterexample?). Also, can we re-write last step as $\lim_{x,y\to 0} f(x)-g(y) = \lim_{x\to0}f(x) - \lim_{y\to 0}g(y)$ and then say that the difference is $>0$ when $\lim f(x)>\lim g(y)$? (and $=$ when the two limits are $=$?)

Comment: No, I mean you will have $c≥ 0$ in general.
What I wanted to say is that $u_k >0$ does not imply $\lim u_k > 0$ in general, it just implies $\lim u_k ≥ 0$ (of course, you can replace $\geq$ by "either $>$ either $=$" but the symbol $\geq$ has the same meaning ...).

You can replace the limit of the difference by the difference of the limits if the two functions are continuous, yes. Try to prove it yourself, this in the only way to understand things.